# Check condition in shell script

Tags: 12.04, command-line, pulseaudio

I have the following command:

```
pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#1/){/(Volume:.*)/; print "$1\n"}'
```

it returns the output as:

```
Volume: 0:  50% 1:  50%
```

it denote the pulseaudio volume for sink 1 is 50%.

So I want to check it in if condition 
the volume <= 50% or not

So how can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command (enhanced version of terdon's proposal):

```
pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#1/){/Volume:.*\s+(\d+)%.*\s+(\d+)%/; exit(1) if ($1>50 or $2>50)}'
```

It will check that both `Left` and `Right` channels are above 50%, and will exit with the value `1` (0 instead)

You can check the exit code with `echo $?`:

```
$ pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#1/){/Volume:.*\s+(\d+)%.*\s+(\d+)%/; exit(1) if ($1<=50 or $2<=50)}'
$ echo $?
0
```

**UPDATE**:

To include the following command in a shell script, simply use the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#1/){/Volume:.*\s+(\d+)%.*\s+(\d+)%/; exit(1) if ($1>50 and $2>50)}'
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Volume > 50%"
else
    echo "Volume <= 50%"
fi
```

Comment: I want check the volume is <= 50, if it is <=50 then I want to execute some logic otherwise goes to the else block

Comment: I've updated my answer, please have a look to the shell sample code for a possible use.